# Where is the http-request during the time when a dns-client resolves a domain-name?

Tags: dns

I am running a linux-pc with debian-based distro with firefox and as a dns-client a have dnsmasq.

Suppose that firefox is set to delete the cache after it close.

Where is/sits/exists the http-request during the time when my dns-client resolves a domain-name?

Answer (score 1):

If it exists anywhere, it only exists in the browser. Resolving the target hostname is the first step in establishing the connection over which the HTTP request will be sent; only then can the browser start sending the request.

Comment: Unless you are behind a SOCKS5 proxy, for example, and you delegate the name resolution. In that case, from your point of view, both the request and the resolution (in the largest sense of the word) are happening somewhere else.